# Why does adding a value to list<> makes list not editable in unity inspector

Tags: unity, c#

I am adding elements from the first list to another similar list, but it makes first not editable in the Unity Inspector. Whenever I try to change values from the inspector it makes them again 0. While If I comment list.Add() I can change values in the inspector.

```
[Serializable]
public class Characterz
{
  public string Name;
  public int Age;
  public float Gold;
}




public class Actor: MonoBehaviour
{
     public List<Characterz> kings=  new List<Characterz>();

    public List<Characterz> Actors = new List<Characterz>();

     void Start()
     {
        for (int y = 0; y < 30; y++)
         {
             Actors.Add(new Characterz());
             if (y < 4)
             {

                 //I need to comment following line to change Actors
                // list value in editor 
                 kings.Add(Actors[y]);
             }

         }
      }

}
```

Comment: It looks like some code is missing here. You reference members `Position` and `PositionType` inside the `Characterz` class, but those don't appear in the definition of `Characterz` at the top. Can you clarify? Try boiling this down to a minimal, complete, verifiable example, removing anything that isn't required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DMGregory I edited code before uploading here as there are many variables which will makes code clumsy. Position and other variables are part of characterz class.